# php 7.4.2 некорректная работа unary union для массива

Tags: php

имеется строка кода

```
foreach ($data['planes'] as $plane) {
    $data['pacients']+=$schedule->selectByDate($plane['date'],$departmentID);
}
```

пишется на Codeigniter 4.

`selectByDate` возвращает из таблицы записи с соответствующими датами (`$plane['date']`) и отделениями(`$departmentID`)

На localhost (Windows 10, xampp 7.4.2) код работает как полагается, в результате в массиве все ожидаемые значения. Стоило перенести всё (и код и бд 1 в 1) на Ubuntu 20.04, apache 2.4, php 7.4.3 и в результате в массиве сохраняется только первое значение. Видимо неправильная работа команды += и что-то связано с настройками php?

Comment: Значит базы разные. Проверяйте внимательно содержимое таблицы

Comment: базы одинаковые, потому что делала selectByDate, но не через +=, а через array_push и результат вернулся ожидаемый. но array_push не подходит ибо возвращает массив в массиве

Comment: Вы не перепутали оператор сложения `+` с оператором конкатенации строк `.`?

Comment: но на localhost это работает

Comment: Проверьте так на локалхосте и посмотрите, что получится `foreach ($data['planes'] as $plane) {$tmp = $schedule->selectByDate($plane['date'],$departmentID); echo $tmp . '<br\>';
    $data['pacients']+=tmp;
}`

Comment: в итоге оказывается на локалхост аналогично.  Если использовать оператор конкатенации то ошибка Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем вопрос решен через array_push:

array_push($data['pacients'],$schedule->selectByDate($plane['date'],$departmentID)).

С той поправкой, что теперь selectByDate возвращает не getResultArray(), а getRowArray()